# Site displays with Curl but not within the browser

Tags: debian, dns, apache-http-server, curl, bind

I've set up a dev-enviroment on Debian 7 and installed the following services:

- Apache
- Bind9

I have one site that is reachable through "asix.debian.local". I've set up the zone and added NS and A registry to the db.debian.local file.

Everything is working, this is the response I get with curl:

"curl asix.debian.local"

Apache default

## It works!!

### Aquest es la pagina de benvinguda de ASIX

So I guessed I got everything up and working, but when I type in the same URL in browser, I get "Server not found error - Iceweasel can't find the server at asix.debian.local."

Only nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf is the local IP of the server.

Why can't browser reach the website if curl did?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you use browser on the same machine you use curl?

Comment: Yes, both on Debian 7, it really makes no sense.

Comment: I mean on the same machine, no the same OS

Comment: Yes, they are..

Comment: What you have configured in /etc/nsswitch.conf? Did you try to add record in /etc/hosts?

Comment: /etc/nsswitch.conf
hosts:          files dns mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] mdns4

Comment: And if I define the hosts in /etc/hosts manually it does work :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such case please add line in /etc/nsswitch.conf

```
hosts: files dns mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] mdns4
```

to be

```
hosts: dns files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] mdns4
```

Comment: Did it sir, still the same, curl works, ping works, wget works, just the browser ain't finding the server. It's really strange :S

Comment: Please restart the browser and try again, because some time browser cache DNS requests

Comment: I feel so stupid... That's what happens when you don't stop to think.

I knew it was a stupid thing. Thanks a lot, it works now

Comment: @Borjante, there are no stupid questions, there can be stupid answers :) And sometime everyone just stuck

Comment: You are completely right

Answer (score 6):

For someone reading this in the future:

For me it wasn't a DNS issue but one with **https**:

`curl my-domain.com` worked because it used http protocol.
However, modern browsers seem to always attempt to use https nowadays and that's not always obvious.

So for me, setting up letsencrypt and enabling https solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the headers is what worked for me:

```js
  // headers: {
  //   "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
  // },
```